# Split the xml file into multiple xml files using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I have a complete docbook xml file there are  nested `<section>` elements, I want to split xml base on the `<section>` tag, Could you please support to sort out this concern for your reference here with attached input sample and required output. Thanks in advance

**Input File:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<section id="audit">
    <sectioninfo>
        <titleabbrev>Abbrev title here</titleabbrev>
        <title>I am title</title>
    </sectioninfo>
    <para>Content here</para>
    <para>content here</para>
    
    <section id="introduction">
        <sectioninfo>
            <titleabbrev>Introduction</titleabbrev>
            <title>Introduction</title>
        </sectioninfo>
        
        <section id="aag_1">
            <sectioninfo>
                <titleabbrev>1.01</titleabbrev>
                <title>1.01</title>
            </sectioninfo>
            <para>Content here</para>
        </section>
        
        <section id="aag_2">
            <sectioninfo>
                <titleabbrev>1.02</titleabbrev>
                <title>1.02</title>
            </sectioninfo>
            <para>Content here</para>
        </section>
    </section>
</section>
```

**Required Output File:**

**section_audit.xml**

```
<section id="audit">
    <sectioninfo>
        <titleabbrev>Abbrev title here</titleabbrev>
        <title>I am title</title>
    </sectioninfo>
    <para>Content here</para>
    <para>content here</para>
</section>
```

**section_introduction.xml**

```
<section id="introduction">
    <sectioninfo>
        <titleabbrev>Introduction</titleabbrev>
        <title>Introduction</title>
    </sectioninfo>
</section>
```

**section_aag_1.xml**

```
<section id="aag_1">
    <sectioninfo>
        <titleabbrev>1.01</titleabbrev>
        <title>1.01</title>
    </sectioninfo>
    <para>Content here</para>
</section>
```

**section_aag_2.xml**

```
<section id="aag_2">
    <sectioninfo>
        <titleabbrev>1.02</titleabbrev>
        <title>1.02</title>
    </sectioninfo>
    <para>Content here</para>
</section>
```

**XSL File:**

```
<xsl:for-each select="chapter/section">
    <xsl:variable name="output" select="concat(@id, '.xml')"/>
    <xsl:result-document href="{concat('section_', $output)}" method="xml" encoding="utf-8">         
        <book>
            <xsl:if test="@id">
                <xsl:attribute name="id" select="@id"/>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:copy-of select="ancestor::book/bookinfo" copy-namespaces="no"/>
            <section>
                <xsl:if test="@id">
                    <xsl:attribute name="id" select="@id"/>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:copy-of select="." copy-namespaces="no"/>
            </section>
        </book>
    </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use recursion e.g.

```
  <xsl:template match="section[@id]">
    <xsl:result-document href="section_{@id}.xml">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:result-document>
  </xsl:template>
```

or even simpler

```
  <xsl:template match="section[@id]">
    <xsl:result-document href="section_{@id}.xml">
      <xsl:next-match/>
    </xsl:result-document>
  </xsl:template>
```

(plus the identity transformation template e.g declared in XSLT 3 with `xsl:mode` or spelled out in XSLT 2).

Comment: Like that I want output:

Comment: <section id="introduction">
    <sectioninfo>
        <titleabbrev>Introduction</titleabbrev>
        <title>Introduction</title>
    </sectioninfo>
</section>

Comment: Thanks, Martin: How to apply the section child element but not nested section element

Comment: The suggested recursive approach will simply produce a new result document for a nested section, like you wanted.